# Mount a ramdisk with user permission

Tags: permissions, mount, filesystem

I try to mount a `ramdisk` which does not require root permission to work with.
I used

```
sudo mount ramfs -t ramfs /media/typicalramdisk/
```

Which requires root.
So, I tried:

```
sudo mount ramfs -t ramfs /media/typicalramdisk/ -o umask=777,gid=1000,uid=1000
```

but it didn't help. I received `gid` and `uid` via `id -g` and `id -u`.

- I do not like using `fstab`.
- I do not like using `chmod` as I think `mount` should be able to do that.

Is there still any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From `man mount(8)`

> **Mount options for ramfs**
>
> Ramfs is a memory based filesystem. Mount it and you have it. Unmount it and it is gone. Present since Linux 2.3.99pre4. There are no mount options.

`ramfs` doesn't support any mount options including `umask`, `uid`, `gid`. Use `tmpfs` instead.